# How can i set the correct answer to a multiple choice question with AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

i am trying to add the question correct answer to my form.

```
  //question1
   var Title = setupSheet.getRange('B1').getValue(); 
     if( Title != "" ){
      form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      .setTitle(setupSheet.getRange('B1').getValue())
      .setChoiceValues(setupSheet.getRange(2,2,setupSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues());
  }
  else {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to set the choices with the correct option/s included is with the `setChoices()` [function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#setChoices(Choice)). For this you have to create an array of "Choice" objects.

Assuming "form" is a Form object and you obtain the data from the B column (1st row for the title and the rest for the options), i tweaked your code to add the question with the correct answers using the "correct" array, in this case it'll create a question with the option 3 and 5 as correct.

```
 var Title = setupSheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  if( Title != "" ){
    var question = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
    .setTitle(setupSheet.getRange('B1').getValue())

    var choices = setupSheet.getRange(2,2,setupSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
    var correct = [false, false, true, false, true];
    var choicesArr = [];

    for (var i=0; i<choices.length; i++) {
      var choice = choices[i][0];
      choicesArr.push(question.createChoice(choice, correct[i]));
    }

    question.setChoices(choicesArr);
  }
```

Also, bear in mind that the correct answers feature is present only for forms with the "quiz" option activated.

Comment: So is not possible to go get the correct the answer to a cell in spreadsheet? like making the correct answer be the value of cell B5?