# How do I add the right answer to a text item in Google forms using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to create a test but I can't add the right answer using Google Apps Script.
Please help.

```
function createTestForm() {
  var form = FormApp.create('Sport test');
  var textItem = form.addTextItem();
  textItem.setTitle('What is the most popular sport?');
  // How do I add the right answer using Google Apps Script? The right answer is 'Soccer'
  var formUrl = form.getPublishedUrl();
  Logger.log('Form created. URL form: ' + formUrl);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i set the correct answer to a question with AppScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286758/how-can-i-set-the-correct-answer-to-a-question-with-appscript)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides/setup-grading

Comment: I can't resolve it. please help. https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides/setup-grading

Comment: The short answer is that you can't use apps script to assign a correct answer for anything other than Multiple Choice, List or Checkbox. FWIW, though @TheMaster referred you to the FormsAPI,  "normal" apps script also includes `createChoice(value, isCorrect)` for those question types. For example: [MC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue,-iscorrect), [List](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item#createchoicevalue,-iscorrect).

Comment: @АндрійМельников You can connect using `UrlFetchApp` to Forms API See Code.gs and Readme at https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/tree/main/samples/NoLibrary  If you attempt to do this and have a specific issue, you can ask a new question for each issue. But asking for full code is too much work for me with little return. Otherwise, the answer given by Tedinoz is right: Normally you can't set a correct answer for items other than Multiple choice and List. You need the API to do  this.

Comment: Also see https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides/apps-script-setup  and https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides/compare-rest-apps-script#supported_features

Comment: @TheMaster you’ve summarised the position and cleaned up the mistakes in my observations. Do you see value in converting this to an answer so that we don’t have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Tedinoz Converted to an answer. Feel free to add if I've missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in  the [Forms API docs](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides/compare-rest-apps-script#supported_features),

> The Forms Service on Apps Script does not plan to support:
>
> - Subscribing to form events with Cloud Pub/Sub
> - **Setting correct answers for question types that are not multiple choice**

To set correct answer to a question that is a multiple choice or list, you can use [`.createChoice()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue,-iscorrect) directly. For other types like text items, you need to use the API. You can however connect  with the API through Apps script using `UrlFetchApp`. See

- https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/tree/main/samples/NoLibrary
- https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides/apps-script-setup
- https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides/setup-grading

#### Related:

[How can i set the correct answer to a multiple choice question with AppScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286758/how-can-i-set-the-correct-answer-to-a-question-with-appscr)